# how to minify all css ans js files with google closure with nodejs command line

Tags: npm, minify, google-closure-compiler

I am separate folders for css and JS in my web project and I would like to minify all the files google closure and I have installed node and successfully minified single file. My query is how to perform this operation on multiple files in a folder.

I have performed with documentation provided with npm

```
npx google-closure-compiler --js=my_program.js --js_output_file=out.js
```

Let me know how to perform for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Closure Compiler doesn't operate on CSS files.

Comment: Indeed, Google Closure Stylesheets does: https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets